# I would like to use a regular expression to grab everything after, with the replace string function "Sub"

Tags: ruby, regex, expression

```
string = "\\20141014 - Philippe Morion [SPN]\\FRA-LYO-RICL-026\\FRA-LYO-RICL-026.L01\\FRA-LYO-RICL-026\\C\\Philippe 21 Mai 2014\\Classement\\SOC Department\\AOC\\2014"

Firstmod = string.sub /.*C\\/i, 'f|C:\\'

puts "#{Firstmod}"
# f|C:\2014
```

What i want is

```
 f|C:\\Philippe 21 Mai 2014\\Classement\\SOC Department\\AOC\\2014"
```

Comment: use a non-greedy quantifier. Or use a simple match and a concatenation.

Comment: the other way with a simple match: `'f|C:'+yourstring[/C\K\\.*/]` *(where `\K` excludes characters on the left from the match result)*

Answer (score 1):

You can actually make use of the context: the `C\` you want to find is actually preceded with another `\`. You can add it to the pattern that will look like `/.*\\C\\/`:

```
string = "\\20141014 - Philippe Morion [SPN]\\FRA-LYO-RICL-026\\FRA-LYO-RICL-026.L01\\FRA-LYO-RICL-026\\C\\Philippe 21 Mai 2014\\Classement\\SOC Department\\AOC\\2014"
Firstmod = string.sub /.*\\C\\/i, 'f|C:\\'
puts "#{Firstmod}"
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/IV1AcZ).

Or use @CasimirEtHippolyte's suggestion to use lazy matching: [`/.*?C\\/i`](https://ideone.com/UjnJkr).